# Merging TEMP table results across different database queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, temp-tables

Im currently trying to write queries across 2 different databases, with the goal of eventually creating 2 temporary tables of results from each database query such that I can be comparing like-wise data for a single comparison report.

My first query is as follows

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpVLT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmpVLT

Create table #tmpVLT(
[OrigName]  VARCHAR(250),
[mailbox]   VARCHAR(100),
[action]    VARCHAR(100),
[transport] VARCHAR(50),
[startDT]   DATETIME,
[endDT]     DATETIME,
[Direction] VARCHAR(100),
[Status]    VARCHAR(100),
[origPath]  VARCHAR(100),
[filesize]  VARCHAR(100),
[transfertime]  VARCHAR(100),
[transferbytes]     VARCHAR(100)

)

INSERT INTO #tmpVLT

select 
    [OrigName]
    ,[mailbox]
    ,[action]
    ,[transport]
    ,[startDT]
    ,[endDT]
    ,[Direction]
    ,[Status]
    ,[origPath] 
    ,[filesize]
    ,[transfertime]
    ,[transferbytes] 
from 
    [EDI].[dbo].[VLTransfers]
where 
    origpath like '//EDIS%/in/PROD' and 
    direction = 'receive' and 
    StartDT >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())
order by OrigName Desc,  StartDT desc

Select *
From #tmpVLT
order by OrigName Desc,  StartDT desc
```

The results in this query are working as expected, the only change maybe i'd like to see would be to do string manipulation on the `[OrigName]` column and always trim the last 4 characters to remove .txt or .csv extensions - otherwise this  is fine

My second queryworks as well, but id like to combine both queries into one if that's possible and perhaps do the same string manipulation mentioned above but on `[OriginalName]` and remove the last 4 characters of every output

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpEDIS') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmpEDIS 

Create table #tmpEDIS(
[OriginalName] VARCHAR(250),
[FILECatalogedOn] DATETIME,
[filetype] VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpEDIS

SELECT
OriginalName,  
FileCatalogedOn,
'rx' as filetype
FROM EDIPlatform.dbo.RXInboundFileQueue
WHERE FILECatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())

UNION ALL

SELECT
OriginalName,
FileCatalogedOn,
'eligibility' as filetype
FROM EDIPlatform.dbo.EligibilityInboundFileQueue
WHERE FILECatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())

UNION ALL

SELECT
OriginalName,
FileCatalogedOn,
'costfile' as filetype
FROM EDIPlatform.dbo.CostFileInboundFileQueue
WHERE FILECatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())
ORDER BY OriginalName DESC, FileCatalogedOn DESC

Select *
From #tmpEDIS
order by OriginalName Desc,  FILECatalogedOn desc
```

Comment: Combine how join or union?

Comment: @nbk Im thinking UNION. The results I want are where all results are ordered by ( ```OriginalName``` and ```OrigName``` ) and then by the dates being ( ```FileCatalogedOn``` and ```StartDT``` ) all being in one result set

Comment: it is difficult because the columns have different numbers and different names, so the order of the columns is unknown, but basically see that all SELECTs have the **same** number of columns, and union it

Comment: @nbk If I only used Origname and StartDT for the VLTransfers query would that fix the issue? And what might that look like to write all of that as a UNION statement